# Keytool get "signed overrun, bytes=192" when trying to list CACERTS

Tags: keytool

I am trying to list the content of my CACERTS on my desktop computer but everytime I try I get this error :

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed overrun, bytes = 192

The "bytes = 192" seems to be the root cause but I can't find anywhere a plain english explaination.

Can you guys help me ?

Comment: What is the keytool command you are running?

Comment: keytool -list -keystore "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\security\cacerts"

Comment: Getting `SSLHandshakeException` when listing keystore contents is really strange. You can try to list the contents of the keystore using the `KeyStore` api and see if it is the same.